# How to display value if key is equal to variable

Tags: javascript, object, key

I looked around for this specific issue, but couldn't find an answer: If I have a object with a key value pair, or an object with multiple key value pairs, can I check if one of the keys equals some variable and then display just the value if it does?

Honestly, everything I've tried will just confuse people trying to help me. I've tried using different versions of the code below. But, of course, I get both items in the object. Other ways I've tried have been equally unsuccessful or down-right confusing.

```
const object1 = {
    a: 'somestring',
    b: 42
  };

  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    if ('${key} == "a"') {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
  }
```

I would like to be able to compare the key to a variable and return the value from that object. I need to take some json data and compare an item in the json to the key in the object then use the value from the object in a table and a few other places. Hopefully someone has a solution. I am sure it's not as complicated as I am making it.

Comment: What are you hoping to log to the console from this code, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this way ,

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  if (key == "a") {
    console.log(value)
  }
 }
```

Comment: Is there any sense to use `for loop` if you can just check an object value by a key?

Comment: Holy crap, I can't believe I was doing that. I have to apply this to some other weird logic but I think this gets me where I need to be. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

// here I declare a key variable just for example
const key = "a";

if (object1[key]) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${object1[key]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (let key in object1) {
   if (key === 'a') {
       console.log ( `${key} : ${value} `) ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use For in loop

```
const object1 = {
    a: 'somestring',
    b: 42
  };

for(key in object1)
{

   if(key=='a')
  {
       console.log(object1[key]);
       break;

  }

}
```